# In TDD approach can we have Detail Design Document?

Tags: .net, tdd, design-documents

We are newly getting into this TDD approach. Apart from other initial hiccups we are also confused whether to create any Detail Design Document(DDD).
In traditional way we used to follow this path, -
Business Requirement Document> Functional Specification Document> DDD> Construction> Testing>...
in DDD we used to had all the implementation details complete with Class Diagram, Sequence Diagram and Database Design.
We learned that TDD drives the code implementation and follows [Design by Contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_Contract) principle. So all the classes will be created along with the Unit Test cases.

Can you guide me if we at all require any design document; If yes, then what should be the content of that?

Answer (score 1):

In TDD, writing a Detail Design Document is replaced by writing tests.